# Should I pick VS 2010 or 2008 for F# development?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, f#

And is F# support included Express editions of Visual Studio?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734525/getting-started-with-f

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can tell, there is no express edition of F# for Visual Studio 2010.  However, I have seen articles regarding installing a free version of F# for VS 2008.  [Here's one.](https://codemiscellany.blogspot.com/2007/12/do-it-yourself-visual-f-express-2008.html)  [Here's another.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404203314/http://www.11011.net/fsharp-in-visual-studio-express)

But if you're going to use the full version of VS, I'd recommend using VS 2010.

(F# is now supported for the free 2010 shell as well, see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140908064140/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/17/announcing-the-f-2-0-free-tools-for-net-4-0.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, go with Visual Studio 2010.  It has a ton of features over 2008.